# Transform key-value XML into other format with PHP SOAPclient?

Tags: php, xml, soap-client

I want to transform my SOAP request from key-value format to another:

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:AUTH>
      <item>
        <key>username</key>
        <value>testuser</value>
      </item>
      <item>
       <key>password</key>
        <value>xxxxx</value>
      </item>
    </ns2:AUTH>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getProductConfig/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is what I want:

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:AUTH>
        <username>testuser</username>
        <password>xxxxx</password>
    </ns2:AUTH>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getProductConfig>
          <partner_id>1</partner_id>
    </ns1:getProductConfig>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is my PHP code where I create a new SoapClient object:

```
$header = new SoapHeader('chainstore-api','AUTH',$headerOptions, FALSE);

$req = new SoapClient(NULL, $options);
$req->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$res = $req->getProductConfig($params);
echo $res;
```

PS: Currently, It's non wsdl style but I'm thinking about to change to use wsdl too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may sound crazy, but I just fixed this by using WSDL instead.

It is much easier. WSDL file will determine both SOAP request and response.